# excel vba: fill another column with color if this column is not null

Tags: excel, vba

how to write code in vba if I want the another column to fill with yellow color when one column is not null?

For example:

```
if A1,A3,A8,A100 is not null:
fill background of B1,B3,B8,B100 into yellow color
```

If a loop is used would be great because my actual case have 7000 cells to fill instead of 4

Comment: Why don't you just use conditional formatting?

Comment: What do you mean by `null` ? An empty cell is not null.

Comment: @CDP1802 Thanks for point out the difference, yeah, I want to add background if it is empty cell, how could I write the vba code for it?

Comment: OK what determines which of the 7000 cells are checked with the if statement ?

Comment: @CDP1802 the A column is filled with values, this code is simply used to check if A column is empty so we highlight column B to show that we need to add values to column A. There are total of 7000 rows in column B (All are filled with values), so column B indicates the range of rows used for verification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ColorColA()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long, cell As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    lastrow = ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each cell In ws.Range("A1:A" & lastrow)
        If IsEmpty(cell) Then
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) 'yellow
        Else
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Pattern = xlNone ' remove color
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox lastrow & " rows scanned", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: wow, thank you so much. Problem solved!!!